# How to use the value returned from DATE_FORMAT() in the column part of the SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

The table has 8 columns, doctor_id and the other 7 named with the names of the week (sat, sun,..)
If a doctor (ex: id=1) is scheduled in a day (ex: sat) at (ex:10:00:00) it will be inserted like this:

```
INSERT INTO doctors_schedule (doctor_id, sat) VALUES (1,"10:00:00");
```

A trigger will fire every day at a specific time to get today's schedule, it will use this query in it:

```
SELECT doctor_id, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%a")
FROM doctors_schedule
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%a") IS NOT NULL;
```

This query does not threw an error, but it returns all the records without any filter

Answer (score 1):

You cannot dynamically determine column names like that. DATE_FORMAT is going to return a string value, NOT a column name. Something like this may work though.

```
SELECT doctor_id, COALESCE(`Sun`, `Mon`, ... ) AS timeOfDay
FROM doctors_schedule
WHERE CASE DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%a') 
           WHEN 'Sun' THEN `Sun`
           WHEN 'Mon' THEN `Mon`
           ... and so on
      END IS NOT NULL
```

COALESCE returns the first non-null value in it's list; if the "day" fields have empty strings instead of null values, you can `COALESCE(NULLIF(Sun, ''), NULLIF(Mon, ''), ...) AS timeOfDay`, or use a CASE similar to the one in the WHERE (actually, identical except for the `IS NOT NULL` part after it.)

Comment: I edited the question to show a bigger picture of the problem, and can I return the times of the day also?

Comment: As far I understand that edit, the edit just confirms this should work for you; unless the default value for the weekday columns is an empty string, in which case, just change `IS NOT NULL` to `<> ''` (Edit: I just noticed the "return the times of the day" bit, standby.)

Comment: The logic works great, the case statement worked perfectly in the WHERE and it returned the right IDs of today, but I couldn't get the times, it did returned the first non-value of its list ('sun') !. Note: the day columns has a data type of TIME so it will be NULL always if it is empty

Answer (score 0):

if im not mistaken, this will always return null because you are filtering for now not being null

```
> SELECT doctor_id FROM doctors_schedule WHERE DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%a")
> IS NOT NULL;
```

this is your filter:
format current date where the `current` `date` formatted `is not null`

instead of `NOW()` use your date column

Comment: I am using this query in a trigger, it will be dynamically changing and can not be pre-determined

Comment: still you must use a column to check for its validity.
when the db runs NOW() it will always return a value. never a null >> never mind the format.